# Furstenberg recurrence

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, ergodic-theory

I am having trouble verifying exercise 1 [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/10/254a-lecture-10-the-furstenberg-correspondence-principle/). Can I get some hints/solutions? (It's not homework, I am just reading up on it for my own interest.)

> **Theorem 2.** (Furstenberg multiple recurrence theorem) Let $k \geq 1$ be an integer, let $(X, {\mathcal X}, \mu, T)$ be a measure-preserving system, and let $E$ be a set of positive measure. Then there exists $r > 0$ such that $E \cap T^{-r} E \cap \ldots \cap T^{-(k-1) r} E$ is non-empty.
>
> **Exercise 1.** Prove that Theorem 2 is equivalent to the apparently stronger theorem in which “is non-empty” is replaced by “has positive measure”, and “there exists $r > 0$” is replaced by “there exist infinitely many $r > 0$“. $\diamond$

Comment: Applying the theorem to $E$, and then applying again the theorem to $E \cap \ldots \cap T^{-(k-1)r}E$, and so on. No ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don't see how that gets me from "nonempty" to "positive measure"

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. Indicating an off-site link is not a solution.